# Composer install says it's getting correct tags, but does not pull down correct code

Tags: git, composer-php

I have a web application which contains several repos, and I am using Composer to manage which versions of each repo is being used for deployment.

I have explicitly spelled out which tag I want for each repo, and it seems that Composer respects those and tells me it's pulling those tags on Composer Install.

However, when I actually navigate into the directories for each repo, it has not actually pulled the code that's supposed to be associated with the tag.

What am I missing?  Is this an issue with how I'm using composer install, or an issue with how I'm tagging the repos?

**git log --pretty=oneline**

```
e9ba89babf55f8c8ec353499a00b924b3ec32978 (HEAD -> 1.9.7, tag: 1.9.7, origin/master, origin/HEAD, composer/master, master) feat(files): send public file path to JS
```

**inside "repositories"**

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "ripple/admin",
    "version": "1.9.7",
    "type": "ripple-custom",
    "source": {
      "url": "repourl.git",
      "type": "git",
      "reference" : "master"
    }
  }
},
```

**inside "require"**

```
"ripple/admin" : "1.9.7",
```

**terminal output after composer install**

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 updates, 0 removals
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
 - Updating ripple/admin (1.9.6 => 1.9.7):  Checking out master
Generating autoload files
Maintaining patches
```

It should be noted that when I do a clean install using this codebase, it pulls down the correct versions on composer install.  It's when updating that I have the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Composer documentation of `package` repository type:

> Note: This repository type has a few limitations and should be avoided
>   whenever possible:
>
> - Composer will not update the package unless you change the `version` field.
> - Composer will not update the commit references, so if you use `master` as reference you will have to delete the package to force an update,
>     and will have to deal with an unstable lock file.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

Second point describes your case. You should use tags or commit hashes as a reference, instead of branches.

Comment: So are you saying that instead of referencing master, I should be referencing the tag I have set as the version?

Comment: I suggest to not use `package` type at all. If this is your package, add `composer.json` into it and add `vcs` repository with it to main project. But if you need stick to `package` type, it is better to use tags as reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I gave you a point, but I'm lowly so it doesn't appear.